# Pulumi - Calling __str__ on an Output[T] is not supported

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pulumi

I'm trying to create my first project in pulumi and can't move forward because I can't provide my ECS task definition to the service:

```
    task_definition = aws.ecs.TaskDefinition("service",
                                     execution_role_arn=aws.iam.get_role(name="ecsTaskExecutionRole").arn,
                                     family="service",
                                     container_definitions=json.dumps([json_data]),                                    task_role_arn=aws.iam.get_role(name="ecsTaskRole").arn
                                     )

    aws.ecs.Service(ecs_service_name,
                    cluster=ecs_cluster.arn,
...
                    task_definition=task_definition.arn
                    )
```

As a result I'm getting expected:

```
    Calling __str__ on an Output[T] is not supported.
    To get the value of an Output[T] as an Output[str] consider:
    1. o.apply(lambda v => f"prefix{v}suffix")
    See https://pulumi.io/help/outputs for more details.
    This function may throw in a future version of Pulumi.
```

I've studied thoroughly official documentation https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/ and tried to apply approach
`task_definition=task_definition.arn.apply(lambda arn : arn)`

But result is the same.
Tried many other different options, but still not there.

Can somebody please help me to move forward? How to not interpolate Output into string properly? Apparently, official documentation doesn't provide the answer and suggested explanation is not working for me.

Below is the full code without imports:

```
config = pulumi.Config()
data = config.require_object('ecs')

def create_task_def(ecs_service_name, custom_task_definitions):
    container_port_app = data['service'][ecs_service_name]['container_port_app'] if 'container_port_app' in \
        data['service'][ecs_service_name] else data['service']['default']['container_port_app']

    task_definitions = {
        'container_name': data['task_def'][ecs_service_name],
        'container_port_app': container_port_app,
        'image': data['task_def'][ecs_service_name]['image'],
        'is_pinned': data['service'][ecs_service_name]['is_pinned'] if 'is_pinned' in \
            data['service'][ecs_service_name] else data['service']['default']['is_pinned'],
        'network_mode': data['service'][ecs_service_name]['network_mode'] if 'network_mode' in \
            data['service'][ecs_service_name] else data['service']['default']['network_mode'],
        'log_group_name': data['task_def'][ecs_service_name]['log_group_name'] if 'log_group_name' \
            in data['task_def'][ecs_service_name] else ecs_service_name,
        'aws_region': data['service'][ecs_service_name]['aws_region'] if 'aws_region' in \
            data['service'][ecs_service_name] else data['service']['default']['aws_region'],
        'stream_prefix': data['service'][ecs_service_name]['stream_prefix'] if 'stream_prefix' in \
            data['service'][ecs_service_name] else data['service']['default']['stream_prefix'],
        'lb_target_group_port': container_port_app,
        'container_port_db': data['task_def'][ecs_service_name]['container_port_db'] if 'container_port_db' in \
            data['task_def'][ecs_service_name] else '',
        'environment': pulumi.get_stack(),
        'catalina_opts': data['service'][ecs_service_name]['catalina_opts'] if 'catalina_opts' in \
            data['service'][ecs_service_name] else data['service']['default']['catalina_opts']
    }

    task_definitions.update(custom_task_definitions)

    with open('container_definitions.j2') as f:
        template = Template(f.read())
        task_def_data = template.render(**task_definitions)

    json_data = json.loads(task_def_data)

    task_definition = aws.ecs.TaskDefinition("service",
                                     execution_role_arn=aws.iam.get_role(name="ecsTaskExecutionRole").arn,
                                     family="service",
                                     container_definitions=json.dumps([json_data]),
                                     task_role_arn=aws.iam.get_role(name="ecsTaskRole").arn
                                     )

    return task_definition

def create_resource(ecs_service_name, custom_task_definitions):

    current = aws.get_caller_identity()
    pulumi.export("accountId", current.account_id)

    # Get VPC
    vpc = aws.ec2.get_vpcs()
    vpc_id = vpc.ids[1]
    subnets = aws.ec2.get_subnets(filters=[aws.ec2.GetSubnetFilterArgs(name="vpc-id", values=[vpc_id])]).ids

    sg_names = data['service'][ecs_service_name]['security_groups']
    sg_ids = sg_ids_getter.get_sg_id(sg_names, vpc_id)

    ecs_cluster_name = data['service'][ecs_service_name]['cluster_name']
    ecs_cluster = aws.ecs.Cluster.get(ecs_cluster_name, ecs_cluster_name)

    task_definition = create_task_def(ecs_service_name, custom_task_definitions)

    enable_ecs_managed_tags = data['service'][ecs_service_name]['enable_ecs_managed_tags'] if \
        'enable_ecs_managed_tags' in data['service'][ecs_service_name] else \
        data['service']['default']['enable_ecs_managed_tags']
    enable_execute_command = data['service'][ecs_service_name]['enable_execute_command'] if \
        'enable_exec' in data['service'][ecs_service_name] else \
        data['service']['default']['enable_execute_command']


    target_group_name = data['service'][ecs_service_name]['target_group_name']
    target_group = aws.lb.get_target_group(name=target_group_name)

    aws.ecs.Service(ecs_service_name,
                    cluster=ecs_cluster.arn,
                    network_configuration=aws.ecs.ServiceNetworkConfigurationArgs(
                        subnets=subnets,
                        security_groups=sg_ids
                    ),
                    enable_ecs_managed_tags=enable_ecs_managed_tags,
                    enable_execute_command=enable_execute_command,
                    desired_count=data['service'][ecs_service_name]['desired_count'] if \
                        'desired_count' in data['service'][ecs_service_name] else \
                        data['service']['default']['desired_count'],
                    load_balancers=[aws.ecs.ServiceLoadBalancerArgs(
                        target_group_arn=target_group.arn,
                        container_name=data['task_def'][ecs_service_name],
                        container_port=data['service'][ecs_service_name]['container_port_app'] if 'container_port_app' in \
                            data['service'][ecs_service_name] else data['service']['default']['container_port_app'],
                    )],
                    task_definition=task_definition.arn.apply(lambda arn : arn)
                    )
```

'container_definitions.j2' has this contents:

```
  {
    "name": "{{ container_name }}",
    "image": "{{ image }}",
    "essential": true,
    "secrets": [
        {
          "valueFrom": "{{ encryption_key }}",
          "name": "ENCRYPTION_KEY"
        }
    ],
    "networkMode": "{{ network_mode }}",
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "{{ log_group_name }}",
        "awslogs-region": "{{ aws_region }}",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "{{ stream_prefix }}",
        "awslogs-create-group": "true"
      }
    },
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": {{ container_port_app }},
        "hostPort": {{ lb_target_group_port }}
      }
    ],
    "environment" : [
        {"name": "environment", "value": "{{ environment }}"}
    ]
  }
```

I'm executing it from another folder with this **main**.py file:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, '../../../dd-devops/pulumi/modules')

environment = 'dev'
import ecs.ecs_svc_task_def.main as ecs_module

ecs_service_name = 'some_name'

custom_task_definitions = {
    "encryption_key": "some_secret_arn"
}

ecs_module.create_resource(ecs_service_name, custom_task_definitions)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the content of your `json_data` ?

Comment: It's something like: { "name": "some_container_name", "image": "some_image", "essential": true, "secrets": [ ... ]... } I'm loading it from Jinja with: with open('container_definitions.j2') as f: template = Template(f.read()) task_def_data = template.render(**task_definitions) json_data = json.loads(task_def_data)

Comment: This likely your issue, you're interpolating a pulumi output into a string. I'll need the full code to help

Comment: OK, added the full code

Answer (score -1):

The code is extremely difficult to follow unfortunately, mainly because of the use of jinja2 where a JSON object could be used.

If I was to take a guess, it's because you're loading a config object like so:

```
data = config.require_object('ecs')
```

and then interpolating those values into a jinja2 template, which only takes a standard python string.

The `require_object` method returns an `Input`, so you need to resolve it using an `apply`.

I would highly recommend:

- Removing the use of jinja2. It's not necessary here, you can simply build a JSON object using `json.dumps`
- Ensure the JSON object is built inside an `apply` so that you resolve any outputs.

Comment: Thank you jaxxstorm, I'm trying to find out how to change my code. But I'm not getting, do you mean I should hardcode my values into a file or you mean I should not store my task definitions in files at all?

Comment: I can't tell how, but it started working. Actually, I've improved my code later and not using Jinjja anymore, but instead created a dictionary with my task definition in a service specific __main__.py file, then used json.dumps([container_definition]). The only issue now is "error: aws:ecs/service:Service resource 'docx_acs' has a problem: Attribute must be a single value, not a map. Examine values at 'Service.LoadBalancers'." which is very annoying cause I'm doing that according to the documentation and I remember it has been working, but not anymore. But anyway, that's not for this thread.